# Reversing the $T(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Can someone reverse this formula? Sorry if it's too basic, I'm an old guy and my math is rusty :-D

$s =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

If it ain't clear, by reverse I mean obtaining the value of `n` by providing `s`

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$s= \frac{n^2+n}{2}$$
$$n^2+n-2s=0$$
This is a degree two polynomial equation in the variable $n$, whose positive solution is
$$n= \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+8s}}{2}$$

Comment: well, i sure as hell don't remember a polynomial equation :-(. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: The equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two solutions, namely $$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ Never seen this formula?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: Of course I have :-). I've just been away from math for a very long time. I knew it had to be something like that. At first I though it was (a + b)^2, but then I remembered the sign of `n` is wrong.

Comment: And guess what, I wanted to use it in an algorithm of some sort, but now I realised that it won't yield the result I need. Such a shame. At least I ~remembered~ re-learned some of the good stuff.

Comment: It’s perhaps worthwhile to note that if you know that $n$ is a non-negative integer, you can compute it as $\left\lfloor\sqrt{2s}\right\rfloor$.