# Series Summation Problem $1+2+3+\dots+n=k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Given the following formula, in order to obtain a given $k$, you need to
>   find the value of $n$.
>
> $1 + 2 + 3  +\dots + n = k$

For example:

Given $k = 15$, The expression to be used will be:
$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15$

Here $n = 5$

Is there any formula to solve for $n$?

Comment: These are *triangular numbers*.

Comment: I wonder how this is related to [cauchy-integral-formula] ...

Comment: See also [How to get inverse of formula for sum of integers from 1 to n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2041988) and [Reversing the $T(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1778490).

Answer (score 4):

This is a widely known formula for the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

$$k=1+2+3\dots+n$$

$$k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

So by inversing that to find $n$ we get:

$$ n=\frac{-1+\sqrt{8k+1}}{2}$$

---

*Note that this result is obtained by solving the quadratic equation $0=n^2+n-2k$, hence we should have $\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{8k+1})$, but we can eliminate the second solution since you are looking strictly for solutions to the summation itself.*