# How to reverse formula $S = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: quadratics

I'm using this formula $S = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ to calculate sum of numbers from 1 to $n$.

But, I want to recover $n$ value. If I have $S$ value. Is it possible?

If yes, please provide that formula. Thanks.

Comment: It's just a quadratic equation.

Comment: @lulu Bro, I don't have idea on maths equations. Please provide formula. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: If yo *know* that a positive integer $n$ with $S=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ exists, note that $n^2<2S<(n+1)^2$, i.e., you will have $n=\lfloor \sqrt{2S}\rfloor$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please provide some context so that we know what kind of formula would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversing the $T(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778490/reversing-the-tn-fracnn12-formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we  reorder the relation we have,

$2s=n^2+n \Rightarrow n^2+n-2s=0 $

which is just a quadratic equation in n, the roots of which by the quadratic formula are given by

$n=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{8s+1}}{2}$

However $n \in \Bbb{Z}^+$ so we are only concerned with

$n=\frac{-1+\sqrt{8s+1}}{2}$

which completes your answer.

Comment: A tip use \Bbb{Z}^+ instead of Z^+, first one renders into $\Bbb{Z}^+$

Comment: I didn't know how to do that. I'm assuming that these would work as well $\Bbb{Q}^+$ $\Bbb{R}^+$

Comment: Sure, any uppercase letter works (lower case turn out just regular). $\Bbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRST...}$

Comment: Perfect, it's working. Thanks alot :)